# Set "Packaging" to POM file with Maven Gradle Plugin

Tags: maven, android-gradle-plugin, aar

I have an maven gradle plugin in my Android project, that generates the pom files (I only need the POM files, not to actually upload to artifactory).
I am generating an Android libraries (aar), so I need to add

```
<packaging>aar</packaging>
```

to the Pom file. However, the `pom { }` field does not have any "packaging" option. Any idea how to do it?

This is my current code:

```
task writePom {
    doLast {
    pom {
       //packaging 'aar'
    }.writeTo("$buildDir/pom.xml")  } }
```